# How do you add a new line in Markdown math display mode?

Tags: r-markdown, markdown, mathjax

Is there a way to do multiline equations in markdown?

Assume the following relation by De Broglie

```
$$ p = \hbar k $$
$$ E = \hbar \omega $$
```

when rendered in a datacamp workspace, it looks like

[image: The De Broglie relations, as rendered in a datacamp workspace. They have an uncomely vertical space between them. Knowledge after the fact: This is actually poor notation. Don't do this under no circumstances.]

when I am trying to do:

[image: The De Broglie relations, as rendered in a datacamp workspace when using correct notation for markdown math.]

How do you syntactically place LaTeX elements in a markdown math environment, so it gets rendered correctly?

Answer (score 2):

A way of achieving this is through the `aligned` environment in display math mode. In MathJax's LaTeX math renderer, this translates to writing:

```
$$
\begin{aligned}
 p & = \hbar k \\ 
 E & = \hbar \omega \\ 
\end{aligned}
$$
```

… which renders exactly as the second image example in the question.

[image: The De Broglie relations, as rendered in a datacamp workspace when using correct notation for markdown math.]